# How could I include or exclude a class on runtime into my visual studio application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I need to obtain some information about a certain class which is not in the same assembly of my current application, so I have to include it to the running application to take some information using assembly. is it possible to include a class in visual studio on runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat confusing. Doing stuff in Visual Studio is about design or possibly debug time, nothing while the application is actually running.

However what I would recommend you to do is to add the foreign assembly with the add references command in the solution explorer. Then you can use all public classes in that assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You do not include at runte in `Visual Studio`, but in your application. You should use a [Reflection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial) in order to obtain runtime information.

Comment: Oops, Sorry! Yes in fact I wanna include it in the application, I just looking at the reference that was good, but didn't help. I want to get some information about a cs file which is belong to other application or it is just a cs file something like a clear text!

Comment: @Armen: so what you want, if that link didn't help?

Comment: maybe I have to  change my question to this one: What happen to a file when it is included to an application? something, I don't know some property should be changed! am I right?

Comment: @Armen: it depends on file type. If you are talking about `cs`, it's just a code, so it will be compiled and included in your assembly. If you are talking about some `dll` reference, the reference with it will be include in compilation, so you can use any `public` type ddeclared in that assembly.